# Which service use to avoid user to create an account

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin

I'd like to allow users to login to my application through Facebook and/or Google account as seen in different apps. I saw the different api from facebook and google to do that but it looks like it is used for social interaction and i don't need it (like posting on a wall). It just for them to avoid any creation of account and for me to be sure to have a secured login mechanism.

Is that the correct tools?

Answer (score 0):

U need single sign on. I would not be very specific on this. So you may try this as a reference https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/

Hope it helps!